# changing a node type to #text whilst keeping the innernodes with the HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, .net, html, html-agility-pack

I'm using the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) to parse an XML file that I'm converting to HTML.  Some of the nodes will be converted to an HTML equivalent.  The others that are unnecessary I need to remove while maintaining the contents.  I tried converting it to a #text node with no luck.  Here's my code:

```
private HtmlNode ConvertElementsPerDatabase(HtmlNode parentNode, bool transformChildNodes)
{
    var listTagsToReplace = XmlTagMapping.SelectAll(string.Empty);  // Custom Dataobject
    var node = parentNode;
    if (node != null)
    {
        var bNodeFound = false;
        if (node.Name.Equals("xref"))
        {
            bNodeFound = true;
            node = NodeXref(node);
        }
        if (node.Name.Equals("graphic"))
        {
            bNodeFound = true;
            node = NodeGraphic(node);
        }
        if (node.Name.Equals("ext-link"))
        {
            bNodeFound = true;
            node = NodeExtLink(node);
        }

        foreach (var infoTagToReplace in listTagsToReplace)
        {
            if (node.Name.Equals(infoTagToReplace.XmlTag))
            {
                bNodeFound = true;
                node.Name = infoTagToReplace.HtmlTag;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(infoTagToReplace.CssClass))
                    node.Attributes.Add("class", infoTagToReplace.CssClass);

                if (node.HasAttributes)
                {
                    var listTagAttributeToReplace = XmlTagAttributeMapping.SelectAll_TagId(infoTagToReplace.Id); // Custom Dataobject
                    for (int i = 0; i < node.Attributes.Count; i++ )
                    {
                        var bDeleteAttribute = true;
                        foreach (var infoTagAttributeToReplace in listTagAttributeToReplace)
                        {
                            if (infoTagAttributeToReplace.XmlName.Equals(node.Attributes[i].Name))
                            {
                                node.Attributes[i].Name = infoTagAttributeToReplace.HtmlName;
                                bDeleteAttribute = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if (bDeleteAttribute)
                            node.Attributes.Remove(node.Attributes[i].Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (transformChildNodes)
            for (int i = 0; i < parentNode.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                parentNode.ChildNodes[i] = ConvertElementsPerDatabase(parentNode.ChildNodes[i], true);

        if (!bNodeFound)
        {
            // Replace with #text
        }
    }
    return parentNode;
}
```

At the end I need to do the node replacement (where you see the "Replace with #text" comment) if the node is not found.  I've been ripping my hair (what's left of it) out all day and it's probably something silly.  I'm unable to get the help to compile and there is no online version. Help Stackoverflow!  You're my only hope. ;-)

Comment: My answer was obviously wrong - it was just too hard to keep track of all scope blocks when I couldn't see start and end at the same time... :P Anyway, two new questions: 1) Should you really give `parentNode.ChildNodes[i]` the value of the recursion, or should you give it to some other variable, for example `node`? 2) Why do you return `parentNode` and not `node`?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could just do this:

```
return new HtmlNode(HtmlNodeType.Text, parentNode.OwnerDocument, 0);
```

This of course adds the node to the head of the document, but I assume you have some sort of code in place to handle where in the document the node should be added.

Regarding the documentation comment, the current (as of this writing) download of the [Html Agility Pack documentation](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=33903) contains a CHM file which doesn't require compilation in order to view.

Comment: yeah, I got that...unfortunately all the pages in it say "file not found"...though there is a index...